# What's the use of ## operator in the following statement?

Tags: c

```
#define SWAP(x, y, T) do { T temp##x##y = x; x = y; y = temp##x##y; } while (0)
```

I saw this swap macro for C.

Can someone explain how it works and the use of `temp##x##y`?

Comment: [Token Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)...

Answer (score 1):

It concatenates `temp` with `x` and `y` to help declaring a variable of type `T` that would allow the swap to work.

You can use it like this

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

SWAP(a, b, int);
```

the generated code would be

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;

do {
    int tempab = a;
    a = b; 
    b = tempab;
} while (0);
```

it avoids using the same name of the passed variables as you can see, because suppose you define your macro like this

```
#define SWAP(x, y, T) do { T z = x; x = y; y = z; } while (0)
```

then this

```
int x = 1;
int z = 2;

SWAP(z, x, int);
```

will not work.

Comment: And might I just say how *stupid* that is? It breaks on a simple `SWAP(a[0],a[1],int)`. It's like the writer doesn't know what scoping is. In fact the type isn't even needed, that's the whole point of `decltype()` and `auto`.

Comment: Comment written before he changed his answer to defend the original code. Just for posterity.

Comment: @Blindy I do agree with you. It's just that this is the answer and I am not defending the original code, it's just that I think that this is what the macro author was thinking about.

Comment: @Blindy also not going to defend the original, because it's broken, as you noted. However, it's entirely possible that that particular macro significantly predates `decltype()` and `auto`, depending on where it was originally observed in the wild... Still, even without those, it could be better written...

Comment: Of course, by a simple template function, with proper references.

Comment: @Blindy Um... Notice the "C" tag there? No templates or references most likely...